# Is there an Esperanto expression for "globetrotter"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to ask someone if he is a globetrotter (someone who travels a lot). I would like to know if there is an expession in Esperanto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the meaning of someone who likes to travel a lot, I recommend *[vojaĝemulo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/vojagx.html#vojagx.0emulo)* because it is formed out of common Esperanto suffixes and it’s easy to understand for any Esperanto speaker, even if they’ve never encountered the word before.

Comment: Tio estas tre bela vorto.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **mondtravaganto** (or mondotravaganto for easier pronunciation) or just **mondvaganto**.

<sub>In case you need a reference, search [tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com) for mondvaganto.</sub>

Comment: _vagi_ estas ago sencela. Se tia estas la vojaĝo, do tiu vorto bonus.

Comment: La germana traduko de la vorto *globetrotter* estas *Weltenbummler*. *Bummeln* signifas: la vojo estas la celo. Sed mi ne scias kiel ĝi estas uzata kutime.

Answer (score 0):

Mi trovis interrete la vorton "globtrotulo". Ĝi aperas en pluraj retpaĝoj kaj libroj laŭ Google.

Comment: Guglo-tradukoj  ne ĉiam estas fidindaj.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas Mi ne parolas pri la tradukilo de Google, sed pri vortaroj kaj libroj en Esperanto kiujn mi trovis per Google.

Answer (score 0):

Vi povus uzi *mondvojaĝanto*. Ĉefe por iu kiu vojaĝas pro iu kialo (turisma, profesia, ktp). Se temas pri iu kiu simple vagas tra la mondo sencele, do la respondo *mondvaganto* estas pli bona elekto.